# Trigger action filters via external process in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an external process changing the database of my app. Is there a good way to trigger the before save and after save filters for models that get updated, when it is an external process changing it?

Answer (score 0):

A "good" way? The straight answer is no.

You could move the constraints to database constraints, such as NOT NULL etc. This was the original use-case for database-level constraints, and the reason why DataMapper has always supported migrations that add constraints.

It was a bit cocky of DHH to claim that database constraint logic belonged in the application layer. "Opinionated frameworks" gone wrong here IMO.

More details might be useful, but you're gonna have to think on this one.